# NSArrayController and Key Value Coding

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to populate a document based `NSTableView` and control it using the `NSArrayController`. I guess I understood the concepts of [Key Value coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html). However, I fear the `NSArrayController` is not honoring the [Accessor Search Pattern for Ordered Collections](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-CJBBBFFA). Let me explain

I have a class Name Student as defined

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface Student : NSObject {

    NSString* studentName;
    float marks;

}

//Accessor and mutators
@property (readwrite, copy) NSString* studentName;
@property (readwrite) float marks;

//Initializer - Init all resources
-(id) init;

//Dealloc - Release resources
-(void) dealloc;

@end
```

The implementation is

```
#import "Student.h"


@implementation Student

//Synthesize the accessors
@synthesize studentName;
@synthesize marks;

//Initializer - Init all resources
-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        studentName = @"New Student";
        marks = 0.0;
    }
    return self;
}

//Dealloc - Release resources
-(void) dealloc
{
    [studentName release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

MyDocument class is defined as follows which contains an `NSMutableArray` type instant variable

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class Student;

@interface MyDocument : NSDocument
{
    NSMutableArray* students;
}

//Initializers
-(id) init;

//Deallocators
-(void) dealloc;

//Creating the proxy object
-(id) mutableArrayValueForKey:(NSString *)key;

//Array controller uses keyvalue
//coding to call this 
-(void) insertObject:(Student*) s inStudentsAtIndex:(int) index;


@end
```

In IB, the Array Controller's attributes is set to Student object and its instance variables are added to the key. In the binding section, Content Array is bind to File Owner's which is an instance of MyDocument class. The model key path is set to the array name `students`

Here is the implementation of MyDocument

```
#import "MyDocument.h"
#import "Student.h"

@implementation MyDocument

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        students = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    [students release];
    [super dealloc];
}

//Array controller uses keyvalue
//coding to call this 
-(void) insertObject:(Student*) s inStudentsAtIndex:(int) index
{
    NSLog(@"Insert object is called");
}


//Creating the proxy object
-(id) mutableArrayValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSLog(@"Checking if NSArrayController is trying to create a proxy %@",key);
    return students;
}
```

My problem `-(void) insertObject:(Student*) s inStudentsAtIndex:(int) index` is never called. However, if I implement a function name `-(void) setStudents:(Student*)s`, that is called. -`(id) mutableArrayValueForKey:(NSString *)key` is just for debugging purpose; I wanted to see some part of the Key Value coding is working. The behavior is same with or without -`(id) mutableArrayValueForKey:(NSString *)key`

What am I missing ? I am on Mac 10.6.6 with XCode 3.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the Accessor Search Pattern for Ordered Collections section in [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-CJBBBFFA). Quoting the sentence

> The receiver's class is searched for a
>   pair of methods whose names match the
>   patterns `-insertObject:in<Key>AtIndex:`
>   and -`removeObjectFrom<Key>AtIndex:`
>   (corresponding to the NSMutableArray
>   primitive methods
>   `insertObject:atIndex:` and
>   removeObjectAtIndex: respectively), or
>   methods matching the pattern
>   `-insert<Key>:atIndexes:` and `-remove<Key>AtIndexes:` (corresponding to the
>   `NSMutableArrayinsertObjects:atIndexes:`
>   and `removeObjectsAtIndexes:` methods).

So you have to implement the **PAIR**. Your class should implement both -`removeObjectFrom<Key>AtIndex:` and `insertObject:in<Key>AtIndex:`

Comment: I read this 3 or 4 times and I told myself "This isn't my problem! It's not! I won't do it!" ... but this was exactly my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you're said, I'm not sure when `insertObject:` would be called. In IB, you bound the array controller to your `NSMutableArray`, so it doesn't know anything about your `MyDocument` class.

If you want some sort of notification of when a new student is added to your array, you would need to hook that up yourself. One way to do this is to handle the action from the UI yourself (such as if you have a New button), and in that handler add the object to your array, and do whatever other logic is required.